# Python function for selection in dataframe of daily value closest to selected time

Tags: python, pandas, time

I've got a large dataset, containing groundwater measurements over multiple decades. There are multiple measurements per day (some one per hour, others one per 10/15 minutes). The exact timing of the measurement can vary, depending on measurement equipement, usage of the network and method of data transfer, and is (in most cases) not set to the second.

I'm currently looking for a way to present the data in a database, which can only display one measurement per location per day. I'm looking for a way to select the daily value per location closest to 12am.

pd.between_time won't solve this problem, because in some cases there is a measurement directly before and directly after 12am. I would like to select the value closest to 12 am (before or after 12 am).

Due to the size of the dataset, performance needs to be quick. There are some ways of solving this problem with for-loops, but performance will be slow.

Below a small part of the dataset.

```
        Time                 B33
 0      2017-11-26 11:30:03  -2.57
 1      2017-11-26 11:45:01  -2.58
 2      2017-11-26 12:00:02  -2.58
 3      2017-11-26 12:15:04  -2.58
 4      2017-11-26 12:30:27  -2.58
 5      2017-11-26 12:45:01  -2.59
```

Is there a quick method for selecting the daily values, from a column in a dataframe, closest to 12 am or any other selected time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='nearest'` parameter and helper DataFrame with datetimes like you need:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df1 = (df.assign(Time1 = df['Time'].dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta(12, unit='H'))[['Time1']]
         .drop_duplicates())
print (df1)
                Time1
0 2017-11-26 12:00:00

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df, left_on='Time1', right_on='Time', direction='nearest')
print (df)
                Time1                Time   B33
0 2017-11-26 12:00:00 2017-11-26 12:00:02 -2.58
```

Comment: nice solution! I was in the process of transforming the 12:00 into seconds and finding the nearest second by diff..